# Can someone explain this simple concept of a JavaScript loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

Considering this code:

```
var x = 3;
var i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
  x += 1;
  i += 1;
}
println(x);
```

Why would the output be 6? Can someone break it down for me?

I understand that x will continue adding 1 to it's value, but why does the i<3 limit it to 6?

Comment: `i` limits the rounds of the loop to 3. When you add 1 to 3 three times, you'll get 6, right?

Comment: `why limit it to 6` because `x` starts from 3.

Comment: Because `x` has a init value `3`

Comment: What output you were expecting?

Comment: Try `/* ... */ while(i < 3) {/* ... */ console.log(x)} `

Comment: Seriously: take a piece of paper, a pen and start [rubberducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 2):

The answer will be 6 because your initial value of X is 3.
You have only 3 iterations in your while loop.

```
i = 0 => x +1 = 4
i = 1 => x + 1 = 5
i = 2 => x + 1 = 6
i = 3 => exit loop
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks! And, unfortunately, it wasn't a joke.

Comment: Sorry, usually this type of questions are not seen here. 
Good luck with your programming!

Answer (score 2):

Before entering into the loop: x=3, i=0 (i is less than 3, so the condition is true)

After the first step: x=4, i=1 (i is less than 3, so the condition is true)

After the second step: x=5, i=2 (i is less than 3, so the condition is true)

After the third step: x=6, i=3 (i is not less than 3, so the condition is false)

Because the condition is false, it is exited from the loop and the value of x is printed in the output.

- Also, println() is not defined in JavaScript. We can use console.log().

Answer (score 1):

I will explain it step by step

while loop will take values, while i is smaller than 3 right.

X starts as 3 and i starts as 0.

While checks if i < 3. (it is 0 for now )
(x+=1 means x = x + 1 (same for i ))

i was 0, so while loop will start working.
x will become 4 and i will become 1.

second run: i is 1 still lower than 3 so while loop will keep working.

x will become 5 and i will become 2

i is still lower than 3 so while loop will keep working
x will become 6 and i will become 3

now i is equal to 3 so no longer lower than 3. While loop will stop working and you will get the outputs.

But if console.log (x) was in the while loop. You will get all the x results.
The output would be:
4
5
6

So, if your question is why am I getting only 6 as an output? It is because your function comes after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The code of

```
var x = 3;
var i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
  x += 1;
  i += 1;
}
```

increments `x` and `i` repeatedly. Initially, `i` is 0, which is important, as its incrementation's result determines whether the loop should continue. Since the loop criteria is that `i < 3` is (still) true, starting from 0 and adding 1 to the value of `i`, your loop's block will be executed 3 times (it's executed for i=0, then it's executed for i=1 and then it's executed for i=2 and finally, for i=3 it's not executed, because the condition of `i < 3` is no longer true when i=3).

Since the loop block is executed 3 times and both `i` and `x` is incremented by 1 at each execution, their value increases by the same value during the process. Since `i` was increased by 1 a total of three times, its value was changed from 0 to 3 (0 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 3). Since the initial value of `x` was 3, it changed from 3 to 6 (3 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6).